# What does the phrase 'the precipitate of' mean

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning

In this following context, what does the phrase 'the precipitate of' mean?

How should I take this bold and italic sentence?

Context:

> Thus this subconscious life-stream, or bhava∫ga-sota, can be called the **precipitate** of all our former actions and experiences, which
> must have been going on since time immemorial and must continue for
> still immeasurable periods of time to come.

Source: P. 15
Fundamentals of Buddhism"
by Nyanatiloka Mahåthera

Comment: You can see the word "precipitation" in there, which is a chemical term but also a word for rain, snow etc. Presumably it means the end result or product created as the after effect of our former actions and experiences.

Comment: Should I take this as: subconscious life-stream is the result or outcome of all our past actions and experiences? @ralph.m. Thanks.

Comment: I'd say more result than outcome. Our past actions and experiences all combine to produce our subconscious life-stream.

Comment: Why don't you ask about this on Bhuddism Stack Exchange?  To be honest with you, I'm not sure what the writer actually means here. It doesn't really make much sense to me. This seems to be more about religion/theology than the use of the English language.

Answer (score 1):

In chemistry, you sometimes do a chemical reaction with a *solution*  which forms a solid substance to form as tiny particles in the solution.  What you usually see is the solution becoming cloudy, or the fine particles falling to the bottom of the test tube.

> Passing carbon dioxide through a solution of calcium hydroxide causes a precipitate of calcium carbonate to form.

The writer is using this as a metaphor.  Our former lives and experiences "come out of solution" and form a tangible "solid mass" called a subconscious life-stream.

Comment: Thanks @James K. Did you mean 'former lives and experiences creat subconscious life-stream.'?

Comment: Yes, the analogy is that the former lives are like the solution of the chemical, and the subconscious life stream is the solid product that the chemical reaction forms.